# Selected to Active texture baking incorrect colors + Blurry texture

Tags: texture-baking

I have this voxel model and it's pretty high poly. So what I do is decrease the number of polygons using blender and after that I bake using selected to active on the original object to the copy object. Though I've noticed that it bakes the colors incorrectly:

Original:

[image: ORIGINAL MODEL]

Baked:

[image: COPY MODEL]

Not only that, but the texture also comes out blurry, probably because it tries to smooth out the texture, even though I really don't want it to:

Original:

[image: ORIGINAL MODEL]

Baked:

[image: COPY IMAGE]

Is there a way I can fix these 2 problems? If you want to reproduce this for yourself, follow the steps I made in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MY3rsq5JGw.

**Update:**

I fixed the incorrect color problem! I unticked "Interpolation" and "Mip Map" from the Original's Image Sampling panel, and then baked the texture. I still have the blurry texture problem, though. What I noticed is that the texture image itself isn't blurry, only in the model it's blurry.

Comment: The blurring is from the "interpolation" in the image sampling panel.

Comment: Bump number one

Comment: Add it to a material, then look at it. Make sure that the interpolation is disabled in the sampling panel for the viewing material.

Comment: I added it to a material and disabled interpolation and it didn't worked. It looked like changing any values in the image sampling window doesn't seem to affect anything on the material.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the incorrect color baking problem by unticking "Interpolation" and "Mip Map" from the original's "Image Sampling" panel, and then baked the texture. As I'm using the model in Unity, I fixed the blurry texture by setting some values in Unity's inspector panel.